# TypeError: Object is not a function (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying compiling the login file, the code compiles successfully in the terminal, but for some reason, I get this error in the browser showing

> "TypeError: Object is not a function (anonymous function)"

with this code below.

```
export default () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
    const [formInput, setFormInput] = useDispatch({
           name:"",
          password:"",
       })
```

Here is the full code of login file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {signIn} from '../../Controllers/Redux/authSlice'

import './login.css'

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [formInput, setFormInput] = useDispatch({
        name:"",
        password:"",
    }) 

    function inputChanged(e){
        setFormInput({
            ...formInput,
            [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        })
    }
    function submit(e){
        dispatch(signIn(formInput));
        e.preventDefault();
    }


    return(
        <div className = "loginBG">
            <form className = 'login-panel'>
                <h1>Login:</h1>
                <input name ='name' placeholder = 'Name' onChange={inputChanged} value = {formInput.name}></input>
                <input name='password' type='password' placeholder ='Password' onChange={inputChanged} value ={formInput.password}></input>
                <button type="submit" onClick={submit}>Login
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here is the auth reducer file that I import into the login file.

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const slice = createSlice({
    name:"auth",
    initialState:{
        admin:false,
        LoggedIn:false,
    },
    reducers:{
        signIn:(state,action) =>{
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
            const {name,password} = action.payload;
            state.LoggedIn = true;
            state.admin = true;
        },
        signOut:(state) => {
            state.LoggedIn = false;
            state.admin = false;
        },
        createUser:(state,action) => {
            
        }
    }
})

export default slice.reducer;

export const {signIn,signOut,createUser} = slice.actions;
```

So, Why I'm getting this error? And What's the solution... Help me

Comment: So what is the full error? Where does it occur? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67202787/edit) your post to include details.

Comment: `[formInput, setFormInput] = useDispatch` you sure it's not `useState`?

Comment: Yes, Got it, it should be useState. thanks @NadiaChibrikova